# POST list of dictionaries and update or create

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Im trying to make my django-rest-framework to accept a list of dicts for updating or creating many objects in one api-call.

My model:

```
class Order(models.Model):

    internal_id = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    external_id = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
```

My seriallizer:

```
class SimpleOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
```

My view:

```
class CreateListMixin():
    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(kwargs.get('data', {}), list):
            kwargs['many'] = True
        return super().get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)





class OrderViewSet(CreateListMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SimpleOrderSerializer
    lookup_field = 'internal_id'
```

This code works great if I POST a list of dictionaries with new `internal_id` values, but if I include a value that already exists I want to update that object. Is this possible with django-rest-framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible but you'll have to provide your own `create` method on the serializer. I would suggest you to read about the ["Customizing multiple create" part of the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-create).

> The default implementation for multiple object creation is to simply call `.create()` for each item in the list. If you want to customize this behavior, you'll need to customize the `.create()` method on `ListSerializer` class that is used when `many=True` is passed.

So you'll need to create a `SimpleOrderListSerializer` which defines the behaviour you wish, e.g.:

```
class SimpleOrderListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        orders = []
        for item in validated_data:
            # Assuming your "identifying" set of fields is only `internal_id`
            internal_id = item.pop('internal_id')
            order, created = Order.objects.update_or_create(
                internal_id=internal_id,
                defaults=item,
            )
            orders.append(order)
        return orders
```

And then define this serializer as the default list serializer for `SimpleOrderSerializer`:

```
class SimpleOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        list_serializer_class = SimpleOrderListSerializer
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to add this ListSerializer, but it has no effect. I get the same object exists "error" when I try to post a `internal_id` that exists. It is like POST does not use the list_serializer_class. Do I have to do something to the viewset as well?

Comment: @TomasJacobsen Did you try to add a `print` statement in the `update` method to see if it's actually called?

Comment: Yes, tried a print statement just below create and also inside the loop, nothing gets printed to console except the 404 error `"POST /api/v1/order/ HTTP/1.0" 400 129`

Comment: Ah, now we are getting somewhere. If I try to post a list with one or more `internal_id` that exists, I get the error, but if I post a list with only new `internal_id` I get a print from the `list_serializer_class`. Could be possible the `unique=True` on the `internal_id`  is messing up?

Comment: My bad, I got the `update_or_create` call horribly wrong. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Yes, working perfect now, (but fails if `unique=True`) but no worries. Thank you!